# Datagridview column filtering not working

Tags: c#, datagridview, filtering

I have a datagridview that i want to use a filter on. I have found a solution on this site that seems to work for every one else except from me :(

The code is:

```
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = tagsView.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = " [name] LIKE '%" + searchTextBox.Text + "%'";
        tagsView.DataSource = bs;
```

when I use the code, all the content of the datagridview just disappears and thats that. But what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well, maybe your `searchTextBox.Text` value creates such a filter that no rows matching this criteria exists in your gridview?

Comment: What is your column name, Type? What is `tagsView.DataSource` at the time you call? Does that works for you first time this code executes?

Comment: The column name is just "name" and a type string. The tagView er loaded with som data when i call the code. And the code does not work the first time. It just "removes" all rows.